# Probability the number Zero appears in a Canadian Postal code (of format x#x #x#), where x denotes a letter

Tags: probability

first post. Doing some basic probability, and although I got an answer to the question, something's telling me in the back of my mind that I did it incorrectly.

The question is: What is the probability that the number 0 appears in a Canadian postal code (which has three letters and three numbers alternating, such as H3G 1D8, all drawn with replacement)? I know the question is vague in that it doesn't state whether it occurs once, twice, or three times, but I will assume it does mean "at least" once.

My thought process would be that P(0 occurs once) = 1/10 x 9/10 x 9/10 = .081

P(twice) = 1/10 x 1/10 x 9/10 = .009

P(Three times) = 1/10 x 1/10 x 1/10 = .001

so P (0 occurs) =  .081 + .009 + .001 = .091, or 9.1%.

The thought that made me doubt this was that shouldn't the probability of zero occurring at least once be 1-P(zero doesn't occur)? And P(Zero doesn't occur) would be 9/10 x 9/10 x 9/10 = .729, meaning 1-P(zero doesn't occur) = 0.271.

If someone could clarify what the answer is and where I am mistaken it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all for your time!

Comment: Your second method is correct.  The mistake in your first answer is that you didn't take into account where the 0's occur, so you have to multiply your first two numbers by 3 (since 0 can occur in 3 different places, and two 0's can also occur in 3 different places).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to account for the fact that 0 could occur in the other 2 slots as well for having one 0, so it should be more like $3 * (\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{9} * \frac{1}{9})$. Then, for having 0 twice, you can also have 3 ways of arranging the non-0 digit: $3 * (\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{9})$. However, there is only one total way to have 3 0's. So the final answer should look like:

$3 * (\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{9} * \frac{1}{9}) +  3 * (\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{9}) + 1 * (\frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10} * \frac{1}{10}) = .243 + .027 + .001 = .271$

So yes, your second method was the one that was executed correctly. The first had only a minor error.